swap on zfs blocks system
Over the past few years I have had two laptops exhibiting the same behaviour.
One was fixed by re-installation.
The other is currently broken.
The issue is that as soon as the laptop starts swapping it feels as if it freezes, when sitting at it.
Remotely you can see it does not freeze completely:
Both run swap on LUKS encrypted partition with zfs on-top.
The new system has an additional 8 GB swap, that works as expected: The freezing starts when the 8 GB is used.
$ cat /proc/swaps 
Filename                                Type            Size            Used            Priority
/dev/zd16                               partition       31457276        3816            -3
/dev/dm-1                               partition       8388604         494612          -2

top says:
top - 15:48:30 up 22 min,  4 users,  load average: 24.41, 8.42, 4.94
Tasks: 436 total,  13 running, 352 sleeping,  71 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.0 us,100.0 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st 
GiB Mem :     62.2 total,      0.4 free,     61.9 used,      0.1 buff/cache     
GiB Swap:     38.0 total,     29.7 free,      8.3 used.      0.4 avail Mem 

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND            
  22433 root       0 -20       0      0      0 R  82.6   0.0   0:17.96 zvol               
  21398 root       0 -20       0      0      0 R  80.2   0.0   0:18.93 z_wr_int           
  21395 root       1 -19       0      0      0 R  65.3   0.0   0:13.66 z_wr_iss           
  22420 root       0 -20       0      0      0 R  60.2   0.0   0:20.14 zvol               
    445 root       1 -19       0      0      0 R  56.2   0.0   0:25.17 z_wr_iss           
  21396 root       1 -19       0      0      0 R  45.1   0.0   0:13.17 z_wr_iss           
   1720 root      20   0       0      0      0 R   1.0   0.0   0:00.21 txg_sync           
  19644 root      20   0       0      0      0 D   0.8   0.0   0:04.56 kworker/u8:3+even+ 
  19788 root      20   0       0      0      0 R   0.8   0.0   0:05.43 kworker/u8:6+flus+ 

dmesg --follow says:
[ 1476.236032] INFO: task vdev_autotrim:502 blocked for more than 122 seconds.
[ 1476.236052]       Tainted: P           OE      6.8.0-39-generic #39-Ubuntu
[ 1476.236057] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[ 1476.236060] task:vdev_autotrim   state:D stack:0     pid:502   tgid:502   ppid:2      flags:0x00004000
[ 1476.236068] Call Trace:
[ 1476.236073]  <TASK>
[ 1476.236080]  __schedule+0x27c/0x6b0
[ 1476.236093]  schedule+0x33/0x110
[ 1476.236100]  cv_wait_common+0x102/0x140 [spl]
[ 1476.236220]  ? __pfx_autoremove_wake_function+0x10/0x10
[ 1476.236230]  __cv_wait+0x15/0x30 [spl]
[ 1476.236263]  vdev_autotrim_wait_kick+0x4d/0xb0 [zfs]
[ 1476.237396]  vdev_autotrim_thread+0x704/0x7b0 [zfs]
[ 1476.238429]  ? __pfx_vdev_autotrim_thread+0x10/0x10 [zfs]
[ 1476.239451]  ? __pfx_thread_generic_wrapper+0x10/0x10 [spl]
[ 1476.239503]  thread_generic_wrapper+0x5f/0x70 [spl]
[ 1476.239540]  kthread+0xf2/0x120
[ 1476.239548]  ? __pfx_kthread+0x10/0x10
[ 1476.239553]  ret_from_fork+0x47/0x70
[ 1476.239560]  ? __pfx_kthread+0x10/0x10
[ 1476.239564]  ret_from_fork_asm+0x1b/0x30
[ 1476.239573]  </TASK>
[ 1599.259263] INFO: task zvol:385 blocked for more than 123 seconds.
[ 1599.259282]       Tainted: P           OE      6.8.0-39-generic #39-Ubuntu
[ 1599.259286] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[ 1599.259290] task:zvol            state:D stack:0     pid:385   tgid:385   ppid:2      flags:0x00004000
[ 1599.259299] Call Trace:
[ 1599.259304]  <TASK>
[ 1599.259310]  __schedule+0x27c/0x6b0
[ 1599.259323]  schedule+0x33/0x110
[ 1599.259327]  schedule_preempt_disabled+0x15/0x30
[ 1599.259332]  rwsem_down_read_slowpath+0x284/0x4d0
[ 1599.259343]  ? __list_add+0x17/0x40 [zfs]
[ 1599.260419]  down_read+0x48/0xd0
[ 1599.260433]  dbuf_dirty+0x4b9/0x730 [zfs]
[ 1599.261429]  dmu_buf_will_dirty_impl+0xd2/0x1b0 [zfs]
[ 1599.262416]  dmu_buf_will_dirty+0x16/0x30 [zfs]
[ 1599.263402]  dmu_write_uio_dnode+0x92/0x170 [zfs]
[ 1599.264394]  zvol_write+0x250/0x400 [zfs]
[ 1599.265386]  zvol_write_task+0x12/0x30 [zfs]
[ 1599.266378]  taskq_thread+0x1f6/0x3c0 [spl]
[ 1599.266427]  ? __pfx_default_wake_function+0x10/0x10
[ 1599.266440]  ? __pfx_zvol_write_task+0x10/0x10 [zfs]
[ 1599.267440]  ? __pfx_taskq_thread+0x10/0x10 [spl]
[ 1599.267488]  kthread+0xf2/0x120
[ 1599.267496]  ? __pfx_kthread+0x10/0x10
[ 1599.267500]  ret_from_fork+0x47/0x70
[ 1599.267506]  ? __pfx_kthread+0x10/0x10
[ 1599.267510]  ret_from_fork_asm+0x1b/0x30
[ 1599.267517]  </TASK>
[ 1599.267529] INFO: task txg_sync:492 blocked for more than 123 seconds.
[ 1599.267537]       Tainted: P           OE      6.8.0-39-generic #39-Ubuntu
[ 1599.267542] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[ 1599.267545] task:txg_sync        state:D stack:0     pid:492   tgid:492   ppid:2      flags:0x00004000
[ 1599.267553] Call Trace:
[ 1599.267555]  <TASK>
[ 1599.267558]  __schedule+0x27c/0x6b0
[ 1599.267564]  ? default_wake_function+0x1a/0x40
[ 1599.267572]  schedule+0x33/0x110
[ 1599.267577]  taskq_wait+0x9c/0xd0 [spl]
[ 1599.267608]  ? __pfx_autoremove_wake_function+0x10/0x10
[ 1599.267615]  dmu_objset_sync+0x30d/0x4b0 [zfs]
[ 1599.268611]  dsl_dataset_sync+0x5e/0x200 [zfs]
[ 1599.269610]  dsl_pool_sync+0x9b/0x410 [zfs]
[ 1599.270697]  spa_sync_iterate_to_convergence+0xde/0x220 [zfs]
[ 1599.271737]  spa_sync+0x321/0x620 [zfs]
[ 1599.272767]  txg_sync_thread+0x1e7/0x250 [zfs]
[ 1599.273791]  ? __pfx_txg_sync_thread+0x10/0x10 [zfs]
[ 1599.274846]  ? __pfx_thread_generic_wrapper+0x10/0x10 [spl]
[ 1599.274895]  thread_generic_wrapper+0x5f/0x70 [spl]
[ 1599.274941]  kthread+0xf2/0x120
[ 1599.274949]  ? __pfx_kthread+0x10/0x10
[ 1599.274955]  ret_from_fork+0x47/0x70
[ 1599.274960]  ? __pfx_kthread+0x10/0x10
[ 1599.274965]  ret_from_fork_asm+0x1b/0x30
[ 1599.274973]  </TASK>
[ 1599.274979] INFO: task vdev_autotrim:502 blocked for more than 246 seconds.
[ 1599.274986]       Tainted: P           OE      6.8.0-39-generic #39-Ubuntu
[ 1599.274992] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[ 1599.274995] task:vdev_autotrim   state:D stack:0     pid:502   tgid:502   ppid:2      flags:0x00004000
[ 1599.275003] Call Trace:
[ 1599.275007]  <TASK>
[ 1599.275010]  __schedule+0x27c/0x6b0
[ 1599.275018]  schedule+0x33/0x110
[ 1599.275024]  cv_wait_common+0x102/0x140 [spl]
[ 1599.275055]  ? __pfx_autoremove_wake_function+0x10/0x10
[ 1599.275064]  __cv_wait+0x15/0x30 [spl]
[ 1599.275094]  vdev_autotrim_wait_kick+0x4d/0xb0 [zfs]
[ 1599.276136]  vdev_autotrim_thread+0x704/0x7b0 [zfs]
[ 1599.277156]  ? __pfx_vdev_autotrim_thread+0x10/0x10 [zfs]
[ 1599.278171]  ? __pfx_thread_generic_wrapper+0x10/0x10 [spl]
[ 1599.278224]  thread_generic_wrapper+0x5f/0x70 [spl]
[ 1599.278260]  kthread+0xf2/0x120
[ 1599.278268]  ? __pfx_kthread+0x10/0x10
[ 1599.278273]  ret_from_fork+0x47/0x70
[ 1599.278279]  ? __pfx_kthread+0x10/0x10
[ 1599.278283]  ret_from_fork_asm+0x1b/0x30
[ 1599.278292]  </TASK>
[ 1599.278312] INFO: task vdev_autotrim:1730 blocked for more than 123 seconds.
[ 1599.278319]       Tainted: P           OE      6.8.0-39-generic #39-Ubuntu
[ 1599.278324] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[ 1599.278327] task:vdev_autotrim   state:D stack:0     pid:1730  tgid:1730  ppid:2      flags:0x00004000
[ 1599.278335] Call Trace:
[ 1599.278338]  <TASK>
[ 1599.278341]  __schedule+0x27c/0x6b0
[ 1599.278350]  schedule+0x33/0x110
[ 1599.278355]  cv_wait_common+0x102/0x140 [spl]
[ 1599.278387]  ? __pfx_autoremove_wake_function+0x10/0x10
[ 1599.278394]  __cv_wait+0x15/0x30 [spl]
[ 1599.278425]  vdev_autotrim_wait_kick+0x4d/0xb0 [zfs]
[ 1599.279467]  vdev_autotrim_thread+0x44e/0x7b0 [zfs]
[ 1599.280510]  ? __pfx_vdev_autotrim_thread+0x10/0x10 [zfs]
[ 1599.281544]  ? __pfx_thread_generic_wrapper+0x10/0x10 [spl]
[ 1599.281595]  thread_generic_wrapper+0x5f/0x70 [spl]
[ 1599.281632]  kthread+0xf2/0x120
[ 1599.281640]  ? __pfx_kthread+0x10/0x10
[ 1599.281645]  ret_from_fork+0x47/0x70
[ 1599.281650]  ? __pfx_kthread+0x10/0x10
[ 1599.281655]  ret_from_fork_asm+0x1b/0x30
[ 1599.281663]  </TASK>
[ 1599.281707] INFO: task zvol:4168 blocked for more than 123 seconds.
[ 1599.281715]       Tainted: P           OE      6.8.0-39-generic #39-Ubuntu
[ 1599.281719] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[ 1599.281722] task:zvol            state:D stack:0     pid:4168  tgid:4168  ppid:2      flags:0x00004000
[ 1599.281731] Call Trace:
[ 1599.281733]  <TASK>
[ 1599.281737]  __schedule+0x27c/0x6b0
[ 1599.281746]  schedule+0x33/0x110
[ 1599.281750]  schedule_preempt_disabled+0x15/0x30
[ 1599.281755]  rwsem_down_read_slowpath+0x284/0x4d0
[ 1599.281763]  down_read+0x48/0xd0
[ 1599.281770]  dmu_tx_check_ioerr+0x3f/0x100 [zfs]
[ 1599.282813]  dmu_tx_count_write+0xe3/0x1d0 [zfs]
[ 1599.283850]  dmu_tx_hold_write_by_dnode+0x3a/0x60 [zfs]
[ 1599.284880]  zvol_write+0x225/0x400 [zfs]
[ 1599.285892]  zvol_write_task+0x12/0x30 [zfs]
[ 1599.286921]  taskq_thread+0x1f6/0x3c0 [spl]
[ 1599.286976]  ? __pfx_default_wake_function+0x10/0x10
[ 1599.286988]  ? __pfx_zvol_write_task+0x10/0x10 [zfs]
[ 1599.287997]  ? __pfx_taskq_thread+0x10/0x10 [spl]
[ 1599.288047]  kthread+0xf2/0x120
[ 1599.288055]  ? __pfx_kthread+0x10/0x10
[ 1599.288060]  ret_from_fork+0x47/0x70
[ 1599.288066]  ? __pfx_kthread+0x10/0x10
[ 1599.288071]  ret_from_fork_asm+0x1b/0x30
[ 1599.288079]  </TASK>
[ 1599.288131] INFO: task zvol:22411 blocked for more than 123 seconds.
[ 1599.288139]       Tainted: P           OE      6.8.0-39-generic #39-Ubuntu
[ 1599.288143] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[ 1599.288146] task:zvol            state:D stack:0     pid:22411 tgid:22411 ppid:2      flags:0x00004000
[ 1599.288154] Call Trace:
[ 1599.288157]  <TASK>
[ 1599.288160]  __schedule+0x27c/0x6b0
[ 1599.288168]  schedule+0x33/0x110
[ 1599.288173]  schedule_preempt_disabled+0x15/0x30
[ 1599.288178]  rwsem_down_write_slowpath+0x27e/0x550
[ 1599.288186]  down_write+0x5c/0x80
[ 1599.288193]  dnode_new_blkid+0xf7/0x180 [zfs]
[ 1599.289207]  dbuf_dirty+0x54f/0x730 [zfs]
[ 1599.290202]  dmu_buf_will_dirty_impl+0xd2/0x1b0 [zfs]
[ 1599.291195]  dmu_buf_will_dirty+0x16/0x30 [zfs]
[ 1599.292202]  dmu_write_uio_dnode+0x92/0x170 [zfs]
[ 1599.293198]  zvol_write+0x250/0x400 [zfs]
[ 1599.294240]  zvol_write_task+0x12/0x30 [zfs]
[ 1599.295260]  taskq_thread+0x1f6/0x3c0 [spl]
[ 1599.295311]  ? __pfx_default_wake_function+0x10/0x10
[ 1599.295323]  ? __pfx_zvol_write_task+0x10/0x10 [zfs]
[ 1599.296336]  ? __pfx_taskq_thread+0x10/0x10 [spl]
[ 1599.296385]  kthread+0xf2/0x120
[ 1599.296393]  ? __pfx_kthread+0x10/0x10
[ 1599.296398]  ret_from_fork+0x47/0x70
[ 1599.296405]  ? __pfx_kthread+0x10/0x10
[ 1599.296409]  ret_from_fork_asm+0x1b/0x30
[ 1599.296417]  </TASK>
[ 1599.296422] INFO: task zvol:22412 blocked for more than 123 seconds.
[ 1599.296428]       Tainted: P           OE      6.8.0-39-generic #39-Ubuntu
[ 1599.296433] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[ 1599.296436] task:zvol            state:D stack:0     pid:22412 tgid:22412 ppid:2      flags:0x00004000
[ 1599.296443] Call Trace:
[ 1599.296446]  <TASK>
[ 1599.296449]  __schedule+0x27c/0x6b0
[ 1599.296458]  schedule+0x33/0x110
[ 1599.296462]  schedule_preempt_disabled+0x15/0x30
[ 1599.296467]  rwsem_down_read_slowpath+0x284/0x4d0
[ 1599.296475]  down_read+0x48/0xd0
[ 1599.296481]  dmu_tx_check_ioerr+0x3f/0x100 [zfs]
[ 1599.297512]  dmu_tx_count_write+0xe3/0x1d0 [zfs]
[ 1599.298535]  dmu_tx_hold_write_by_dnode+0x3a/0x60 [zfs]
[ 1599.299563]  zvol_write+0x225/0x400 [zfs]
[ 1599.300595]  zvol_write_task+0x12/0x30 [zfs]
[ 1599.301619]  taskq_thread+0x1f6/0x3c0 [spl]
[ 1599.301670]  ? __pfx_default_wake_function+0x10/0x10
[ 1599.301682]  ? __pfx_zvol_write_task+0x10/0x10 [zfs]
[ 1599.302702]  ? __pfx_taskq_thread+0x10/0x10 [spl]
[ 1599.302753]  kthread+0xf2/0x120
[ 1599.302761]  ? __pfx_kthread+0x10/0x10
[ 1599.302766]  ret_from_fork+0x47/0x70
[ 1599.302772]  ? __pfx_kthread+0x10/0x10
[ 1599.302777]  ret_from_fork_asm+0x1b/0x30
[ 1599.302785]  </TASK>
[ 1599.302789] INFO: task zvol:22413 blocked for more than 123 seconds.
[ 1599.302796]       Tainted: P           OE      6.8.0-39-generic #39-Ubuntu
[ 1599.302800] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[ 1599.302804] task:zvol            state:D stack:0     pid:22413 tgid:22413 ppid:2      flags:0x00004000
[ 1599.302811] Call Trace:
[ 1599.302814]  <TASK>
[ 1599.302817]  __schedule+0x27c/0x6b0
[ 1599.302825]  schedule+0x33/0x110
[ 1599.302829]  schedule_preempt_disabled+0x15/0x30
[ 1599.302834]  rwsem_down_read_slowpath+0x284/0x4d0
[ 1599.302842]  down_read+0x48/0xd0
[ 1599.302847]  dmu_tx_check_ioerr+0x3f/0x100 [zfs]
[ 1599.303875]  dmu_tx_count_write+0xe3/0x1d0 [zfs]
[ 1599.304881]  dmu_tx_hold_write_by_dnode+0x3a/0x60 [zfs]
[ 1599.305969]  zvol_write+0x225/0x400 [zfs]
[ 1599.306987]  zvol_write_task+0x12/0x30 [zfs]
[ 1599.308009]  taskq_thread+0x1f6/0x3c0 [spl]
[ 1599.308058]  ? __pfx_default_wake_function+0x10/0x10
[ 1599.308070]  ? __pfx_zvol_write_task+0x10/0x10 [zfs]
[ 1599.309110]  ? __pfx_taskq_thread+0x10/0x10 [spl]
[ 1599.309160]  kthread+0xf2/0x120
[ 1599.309170]  ? __pfx_kthread+0x10/0x10
[ 1599.309175]  ret_from_fork+0x47/0x70
[ 1599.309180]  ? __pfx_kthread+0x10/0x10
[ 1599.309185]  ret_from_fork_asm+0x1b/0x30
[ 1599.309193]  </TASK>
[ 1599.309196] INFO: task zvol:22414 blocked for more than 123 seconds.
[ 1599.309205]       Tainted: P           OE      6.8.0-39-generic #39-Ubuntu
[ 1599.309209] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[ 1599.309212] task:zvol            state:D stack:0     pid:22414 tgid:22414 ppid:2      flags:0x00004000
[ 1599.309220] Call Trace:
[ 1599.309223]  <TASK>
[ 1599.309226]  __schedule+0x27c/0x6b0
[ 1599.309234]  schedule+0x33/0x110
[ 1599.309239]  schedule_preempt_disabled+0x15/0x30
[ 1599.309244]  rwsem_down_read_slowpath+0x284/0x4d0
[ 1599.309252]  ? __list_add+0x17/0x40 [zfs]
[ 1599.310294]  down_read+0x48/0xd0
[ 1599.310306]  dmu_buf_hold_array_by_dnode+0x4f/0x570 [zfs]
[ 1599.311341]  ? dsl_dir_tempreserve_space+0x10f/0x160 [zfs]
[ 1599.312359]  dmu_write_uio_dnode+0x5c/0x170 [zfs]
[ 1599.313360]  zvol_write+0x250/0x400 [zfs]
[ 1599.314393]  zvol_write_task+0x12/0x30 [zfs]
[ 1599.315434]  taskq_thread+0x1f6/0x3c0 [spl]
[ 1599.315487]  ? __pfx_default_wake_function+0x10/0x10
[ 1599.315498]  ? __pfx_zvol_write_task+0x10/0x10 [zfs]
[ 1599.316518]  ? __pfx_taskq_thread+0x10/0x10 [spl]
[ 1599.316568]  kthread+0xf2/0x120
[ 1599.316577]  ? __pfx_kthread+0x10/0x10
[ 1599.316582]  ret_from_fork+0x47/0x70
[ 1599.316587]  ? __pfx_kthread+0x10/0x10
[ 1599.316592]  ret_from_fork_asm+0x1b/0x30
[ 1599.316601]  </TASK>

I have the feeling I simply need to do something to /dev/zd16 (aka: /dev/zvol/rpool/swap).
(the 8 GB swap is a 8 GB LUKS partition - not zfs).
$ zfs get all rpool/swap
NAME        PROPERTY              VALUE                  SOURCE
rpool/swap  type                  volume                 -
rpool/swap  creation              Fri Aug  2  0:39 2024  -
rpool/swap  used                  30.5G                  -
rpool/swap  available             176G                   -
rpool/swap  referenced            362M                   -
rpool/swap  compressratio         1.00x                  -
rpool/swap  reservation           none                   default
rpool/swap  volsize               30G                    local
rpool/swap  volblocksize          16K                    default
rpool/swap  checksum              on                     default
rpool/swap  compression           lz4                    inherited from rpool
rpool/swap  readonly              off                    default
rpool/swap  createtxg             1260475                -
rpool/swap  copies                1                      default
rpool/swap  refreservation        30.5G                  local
rpool/swap  guid                  13973446581616721601   -
rpool/swap  primarycache          all                    default
rpool/swap  secondarycache        all                    default
rpool/swap  usedbysnapshots       0B                     -
rpool/swap  usedbydataset         362M                   -
rpool/swap  usedbychildren        0B                     -
rpool/swap  usedbyrefreservation  30.1G                  -
rpool/swap  logbias               latency                default
rpool/swap  objsetid              84726                  -
rpool/swap  dedup                 off                    default
rpool/swap  mlslabel              none                   default
rpool/swap  sync                  standard               inherited from rpool
rpool/swap  refcompressratio      1.00x                  -
rpool/swap  written               362M                   -
rpool/swap  logicalused           364M                   -
rpool/swap  logicalreferenced     364M                   -
rpool/swap  volmode               default                default
rpool/swap  snapshot_limit        none                   default
rpool/swap  snapshot_count        none                   default
rpool/swap  snapdev               hidden                 default
rpool/swap  context               none                   default
rpool/swap  fscontext             none                   default
rpool/swap  defcontext            none                   default
rpool/swap  rootcontext           none                   default
rpool/swap  redundant_metadata    all                    default
rpool/swap  encryption            aes-256-gcm            -
rpool/swap  keylocation           none                   default
rpool/swap  keyformat             passphrase             -
rpool/swap  pbkdf2iters           100000                 -
rpool/swap  encryptionroot        rpool                  -
rpool/swap  keystatus             available              -


From my experience, swap on Linux ZFS does not work, I am trying to avoid it whenever possible.
These are my thoughts:
ZFS is memory hungry, system swaps when low on RAM. Swapping on ZFS eats even more RAM -> the system almost freezes...
